# Integrating Apache guacamole in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, guacamole

I came across a project `Apache-Guacamole` which helps you connect to `remote computers` through a web browser. I am trying to integrate it to a `spring-boot application`, but unable to do so.

The documentation is quite complex to understand. So, can anybody provides a way to implement it. I have been trying this from a week, but unable to finish it.

I found one `servlet` class online, but it is not working.

Any help will be appreciated. Please guide me.

Thank you.

Comment: Even I have been looking for the solution. If you found one please post it here

Comment: Can Guacamole be used as an api in web application?

Answer (score 5):

It is actually quite simple. First implement the example servlet [from the official manual](https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/writing-you-own-guacamole-app.html)

Then annotate the servlet class as @RestController (@Controller might work too) and then override the handler method and set the url mapping.

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(path = "tunnel", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
protected void handleTunnelRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
    super.handleTunnelRequest(request, response);
}
```

Then you can use the endpoint as described in the manual

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what cacaocow posted, if you are using a newer version of spring boot, you may need to include the following in your application properties file.

```
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false

server.tomcat.relaxed-query-chars={,},[,]
```

The first prevents the crash from `org.apache.guacamole.net.SimpleGuacamoleTunnel["socket"]-> org.apache.guacamole.protocol.ConfiguredGuacamoleSocket["reader"]`
and the second allows the guacamole client to send query messages with **{}** and **[]** characters that are no longer supported by newer webservers.

> It is actually quite simple. First implement the example servlet from the official manual
> Then annotate the servlet class as @RestController (@Controller might work too) and then >override the handler method and set the url mapping.

> ```
> @Override
> @RequestMapping(path = "tunnel", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
> protected void handleTunnelRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
>        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException {
>    super.handleTunnelRequest(request, response);
> }
> ```
>
> Then you can use the endpoint as described in the manual